# Backbone Model save with Spring Controller at the back end not working

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, backbone.js, controller, backbone-model

I've used Backbone model at front end with model url as 'Student' and Spring Controller at back end.

I am able to do fetch using the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Student", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Student createStudent() {
    Student student = new Student("Abc","Def");
    return student;
}
```

But the following code for save is not working

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Student", consumes = "application/json", produces =  "application/json",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Student saveStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
    System.out.println(student.getName());
    return student;
}
```

I have changed some attributes of Student at the client side and saved but it is giving me HTTP 400 error with description "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Backbone model

```
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : 'Student',
    defaults : {
        name : '',
        address : '',
    }
});

var student = new Student();
student.fetch();
alert(JSON.stringify(student,null,4));
student.set({name:'john'});
student.save();
```

Student Class

```
public class Student{
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public void Student(String name,String address){
       this.name=name;
       this.address=address;
    }

    public String getName(){
       return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
       return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address=address;
    }
}
```

Comment: add your backbone code for saving...

Comment: @NikolayRusev added the backbone model

Comment: also add your `Student` class and what is the response from server when you receive error code 400 ?

Comment: please inspect the request body which is sent by client , paste it here.

Comment: Request Body
{"name":"Abc","address":"Def"}

Comment: Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/StudentDemo/Student
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request

Comment: Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:598
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/StudentDemo/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: The problem was incorrect conversion of JSON to Student Object in saveStudent() method of spring controller while accepting @RequestBody parameter which was giving the 400 error. I solved my issue by adding an empty default constructor Student() in Student class and adding null to Backbone save method.

In Student class

```
public Student(){
}
```

Backbone save

```
student.save(null,{
    success:function()
    {
        ...
    }
);
```